# Efficient Method for using Multiple Database connection in java

Tags: java, database, swing, connection

Is it efficient method to open database connection for every database operation and accordingly close 
or open the connection at the starting and keep calling the same opened connection for multiple operation and close it when all the activities is done. ?

I am creating a Java Swing application where i have a main frame and using the card layout i am selecting different panel and each of this panel have different database operation to perform. Presently i am having individual connection opened for each panel , so when i open my main application multiple connection gets opened and closed.

As i want to be sure that i am doing the right thing and avoid any bad practice and bottleneck in performance so i am asking this question to Java Experts.

Please suggest .Thanks for all your help .

Comment: kdev: I think yours is a good question; I am interested in the responses and have up-voted it. As a friendly reminder, you may wish to go back to your older threads and accept more answers as this may motivate more to help you in future questions. Best of luck with your coding and with getting good answers to this question. I hope to learn from it too! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't recommended to "create" a new connection for each database transaction. Creating connections is typically expensive. Try using a connection pool which abstracts the connection open and close semantics. That way, your application can call `Connection#close` etc. and behind the scenes the pool will grab and return connections to the connection poll accordingly. There are many solutions out there; DBCP, C3P0 or BoneCP.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use a connection for each operation if you've got a connection pool.  Creating a connection is expensive, but amortizing the cost over all operations by pooling them makes it possible.

You should get a connection, use it, and return it to the pool with every operation, in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer (1+)! I just Googled for tutorials to learn more about connection pooling and hope you don't mind if I  share what looks like a decent link with the OP: [SDN Tutorial: Connection Pooling](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a database is a relatively expensive operation.  Usually what you would do is use a connection pool.  A connection pool holds a collection of database connections that are ready for you to use.  You would grab a connection from the pool, do your queries over that connection, and then return it to the pool (usually this is done by closing the connection).  The connection pool will take care of making new connections to the database in the background so that when you need a connection, you don't need to spend time waiting for one.